# Plugin similar to dashboard

Tags: maven-2

I'm looking for a plugin that will aggregate various reports from our maven project (which consists of many modules). 
I was using dashboard maven plugin but it doesn't seem to be updated lately and I have troubles with the reports it generates (mainly it makes only surefire reports, no pmd, findbugs, cobertura as it should).

So I'm looking for replacement, are there any similar plugins for maven2?

Comment: Sonar is a nice tool but i don't know why it doesn't use the findbugs/pmd/cpd/checkstyle configuration from my project. It wants me to configure it seperatly on sonar server...

Answer (score 3):

Whilst it's not directly a maven plugin, have you considered looking at [hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/)?  It does a fair bit of reporting aggregation for you…  It's worked well for me, but I limit myself to PMD+findbugs+JUnit.

I've heard tell that [Sonar](http://sonar.codehaus.org/) is also a good dashboard, but I've not personally used it.

Comment: +1 for Sonar, Sonar is currently the greatest quality dashboard

Comment: well, I'm using teamcity so switching to hudnson would be to much of a work,
I tried Sonar, but it seams an overkill to run another server just for reports

Answer (score 1):

I've not yet had an opportunity to test it out myself, but I've heard that the [XRadar plugin](http://xradar.sourceforge.net/reports/dynamics/index.html) is pretty good.

It's "Designed for use with , JDepend , PMD , PMD-CPD , JavaNCSS , CKJM , Checkstyle , FindBugs , CLOC , JUnit , EMMA , Java2HTML  and Ant."

The [xradar-maven-plugin page](http://xradar.sourceforge.net/maven-plugin/howto.html) describes how to get started.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see Sonar in action, have a look to the public instance Nemo : http://nemo.sonarsource.org/